# Show/Hide input HTML by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have such inputs, I would like to write a loop which, when the value of insurer is less than 0, hides the input data from HTML, and when it is greater, it shows (leaves). but my feature is not working. Im not got any erros, I don't get any errores, but I tried differently to write If loops and it doesn't work.

My jQuery code
EDIT

```
gadget.functions.InsuranceLimitsBA_MX_Credit_Management=function(){
    var insurer_limit_single = thisPointer.entity.getValue('insurer_limit_single');
    
    if(insurer_limit_single <= 0){
        jQ('[id="insurance_raiting"]').hide();
        jQ('[id="deducitable_percentage_single"]').hide();
        jQ('[id="Deductiblenormal"]').hide();
        jQ('[id="uninsured_credit_single"]').hide();
        jQ('[id="maxOwnRisk"]').hide();
    }
}
```

My source code:
https://jsfiddle.net/Palucci92/awx07mgv/1/

Comment: A number can only be `>= 0` or not. The second `if` is therefor useless (and in this case wrong because both `if`s would be `true` for `insurer_limit_single === 0`

Comment: You should use an id selector `#<id>` instead of an attribute selector which parses the whole DOM for a matching (and unique) element. And you can also combine selectors: `jQ('#..., #..., ...)` which allows you to call `.hide()`/`.show()` only once

Comment: _...it doesn't work."_ - [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> _"**Describe the problem**. "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it."_ + [mcve] _in the question itself_ (and not just a link to an external resource)

Comment: @Andreas its working better butit hides the inputs, but if I change, for example, the number to a greater than zero, it does not show again, how to fix it ?. I mean what is better to use instead hide/show

Comment: You've (in the updated code provided) only used `.hide()` - you need to use `.show()` to show it again, or use `.toggle(boolean)` to reduce the repetition.

Comment: eg `var showIt = insurer_limit_single > 0; $("#insurance_rating").toggle(showIt);`  (or "raiting" to keep the typo)

Answer (score 0):

it's working with @Adreas help.
Code below:

```
gadget.functions.InsuranceLimitsBA_MX_Credit_Management=function(){
    var insurer_limit_single = thisPointer.entity.getValue('insurer_limit_single');
    
    if(insurer_limit_single <= 0){
        jQ('[id="insurance_raiting"]').hide();
        jQ('[id="deducitable_percentage_single"]').hide();
        jQ('[id="Deductiblenormal"]').hide();
        jQ('[id="uninsured_credit_single"]').hide();
        jQ('[id="maxOwnRisk"]').hide();
    }else{
        jQ('[id="insurance_raiting"]').show();
        jQ('[id="deducitable_percentage_single"]').show();
        jQ('[id="Deductiblenormal"]').show();
        jQ('[id="uninsured_credit_single"]').show();
        jQ('[id="maxOwnRisk"]').show();
    }
}
```